# Jquery Load onclick data driven customisation system

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, load

This code is to work in combination with a form showing the results of the selections made on the right hand side of the page by loading the URL of the chosen option in a specified DIV that corresponds to the ID of the product.

function product_analysis(productid, address) {
    if (this.checked = 'checked') {

```
$(productid).load(address);

}
else {

$(productid).load('http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank.html');

}
```

};

Problem is that the query to check if the box is checked or not does not work. If you check or uncheck the box it loads the address of the onclick event.

Any help would be appreciated but please keep in mind that the products are data driven so we cannot have specific IDs but rather IDs built of the Post ID.

Also when the page loads there will need to be some sort of global function which will work out what is 'checked' and load those URLs (products) in their specific DIVs.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Where is the checkbox?  And where is the code for the checkbox?

Comment: onclick="product_analysis(product_1231, 'http://www.divethegap.com/update/products/2010/11/padi-open-water/')"

Answer (score 0):

Beware that you used `=` instead of `==` in the `if()` condition.

Also, have you tried with the `:checked` selector?

`$("#id:checked")`

[JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function product_analysis(productid, address, box) {
    if (box.checked) {

    $(#productid).load(address);

    }
    else {

    $(#productid).load('http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank.html');

    }
};
```

and code for the box

```
onclick="product_analysis('#product_1231', 'http://www.divethegap.com/update/products/2010/11/padi-open-water/', this)"
```